# Show the 5 cities with higher temperature from a text file

Tags: python

I have a text file with some cities and temperatures, like this:

City 1 16

City 2 4

...

City100 20

And Im showing the city with higher temperature with code below.

But I would like to show the 5 cities with higher temperature. Do you see a way to do this? Im here doing some tests but Im always showing 5 times the same city.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys

current_city = None
current_max = 0
city = None


for line in sys.stdin:
    line = line.strip()

    city, temperature = line.rsplit('\t', 1)

    try:
        temperature = float(temperature)
    except ValueError:
        continue

    if temperature > current_max:
        current_max = temperature
        current_city = city

print '%s\t%s' % (current_city, current_max)
```

Comment: it shows the same city because your print statement comes after the for loop. It needs to be in the for loop suite (i.e. indent it with a spacing of 4)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [heapq.nlargest](https://docs.python.org/2/library/heapq.html#heapq.nlargest):

```
import sys
import heapq


# Read cities temperatures pairs
pairs = [
    (c, float(t))
    for line in sys.stdin for c, t in [line.strip().rsplit('\t', 1)]
]

# Find 5 largest pairs based on second field which is temperature
for city, temperature in heapq.nlargest(5, pairs, key=lambda p: p[1]):
    print city, temperature
```

Comment: This seems massively overkill for what is obviously someone learning the language...

Answer (score 1):

I like pandas.  This is not a complete answer, but I like to encourage people on their way of research.  Check this out...

```
listA = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame(listA)

df.sort(0)

df.tail()
```

With Pandas, you'll want to learn about Series and DataFrames.  DataFrames have a lot of functionality, you can name your columns, create directly from input files, sort by almost anything.  There's the common unix words of head and tail (beggining and end), and you can specify count of rows returned....blah blah, blah blah, and so on.  I liked the book, "Python for Data Analysis".

Answer (score 0):

Store the list of temperatures and cities in a list. Sort the list. Then, take the last 5 elements: they will be your five highest temperatures.

Answer (score 0):

Read the data into a list, sort the list, and show the first 5:

```
cities = []
for line in sys.stdin:
    line = line.strip()
    city, temp = line.rsplit('\t', 1)
    cities.append((city, int(temp))

cities.sort(key=lambda city, temp: -temp)
for city, temp in cities[:5]:
    print city, temp
```

This stores the city, temperature pairs in a list, which is then sorted. The `key` function in the `sort` tells the list to sort by temperature descending, so the first 5 elements of the list `[:5]` are the five highest temperature cities.

Answer (score 0):

The following code performs exactly what you need:

```
fname = "haha.txt"
with open(fname) as f:
content = f.readlines()

content = [line.split(' ') for line in content]
for line in content:
    line[1] = float(line[1])

from operator import itemgetter
content = sorted(content, key=itemgetter(1))

print content
```

to get the country with the highest temprature:

```
print content[-1]
```

to get the 5 countries with highest temperatures:

```
print content[-6:-1]
```